# Jquery Mobile start

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am starting Jquery mobile so newbie. Where should I start jquery mobile?.

What books or websites which take advantage of?

help. thanks

Comment: You can refer this link http://jquerymobile.com/resources/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First download whole jquery demo pages from [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/zipball/master).
If you want rapidly see how something is done watch [video tutorials](http://tuts.pinehead.tv/category/jquery/jquery-mobile/)

Check [examples](http://www.jqmgallery.com/) (some of them are native apps) and see what can be done with JQM

Answer (score 2):

[Jquery Mobile Reference Documentation and Demos](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/)

Comment: since jQuery mobile is based on jQuery and you want to master it good, yes

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tim's answer: http://store.elated.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are newest version in http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/.

Some bugs in the previous version were solved. And you could try copy the code samples of controls you need into your project and test them.